# Javascript Safety of checking for out of bounds and accessing an array in the same if-statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
var some_array = ["11","22","33"]

var access_index = 100
   
var accessible = array.length > access_index ? true : false

if(accessible && array[access_index].substr(0,1) === "1") {
  console.log("ok")
} else {
  console.log("not ok")
}
```

My actual code is a bit more complex, but basically I have an array ("some_array"), an index("access_index") and a bool that tells me if the index is safe ("accessible"). So I'd need to check *accessible* before doing the check on *some_array* with the *access_index*.

Checking the index of and accessing an array in one if-statement seems to work fine, as long as the check comes first. However I was wondering how safe and reliable this is. Will *accessible* always be evaluated first and will the rest be automatically skipped if false?

Comment: Note that `var accessible = array.length > access_index ? true : false` is redundant and can be simplified to `var accessible = array.length > access_index`

Comment: *"Will accessible always be evaluated first and will the rest be automatically skipped if false?"* Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [shortcircuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)

In the case of the `&&` operator: if the **left expression** is `false`, the **right expression** is never evaluated.

The same case for the `||` operator: if the **left expression** is `true`, then the **right expression** is not evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify with the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) a bit.

```
if (array[access_index]?.startsWith("1")) {
    console.log("ok")
} else {
    console.log("not ok")
}
```